# How to sort list(Alphabetically) of items in auto-complete drop-down in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```html
<div custom-select name="pSelect" id="pSelect" ng-model="selectedP" ng-trim="false" ng-options="p as p.name for p in data"></div>
```

This is my custom dropdownlist. Data is coming from the json object.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code-writing service. Can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div custom-select name="pSelect" id="pSelect" ng-model="selectedP" ng-trim="false" ng-options="p as p.name for p in data | orderBy:'name'"></div>
```

Are you looking for something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using angular [orderby](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), the above would look something like this.

```
//last attribute of orderBy would depend on ascending or descending.
<div custom-select name="pSelect" id="pSelect" ng-model="selectedP" ng-trim="false" ng-options="p as p.name for p in data | orderBy: 'p': true"></div>

//or set dynamically
    <div custom-select name="pSelect" id="pSelect" ng-model="selectedP" ng-trim="false" ng-options="p as p.name for p in data | orderBy: type : true"></div>
<button ng-click="type='name'"></button>
<button ng-click="type='year'"></button>
<button ng-click="type='other'"></button>
```

Comment: I have tried all the above ways, but i got these errors "angular.js:11653 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting! Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []"

Comment: @Naren need more code, set a plunker. Need to see controller definition. Also need to see how your using the controller in the view.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is an array, you can use the built-in [order-by filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Just add this line in your ng-options

```
ng-options="p as p.name for p in data | orderBy : 'name'
```

This assumes you have a 'name' property, if not change it to whatever property you are wanting to sort by.

You can easily reverse the sort order, by using a '-' operator before the property, such as

```
    ng-options="p as p.name for p in data | orderBy : '-name'
```

Comment: I have tried all the above ways, but i got these errors "angular.js:11653 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []"

Comment: If you are receiving those errors, something else is wrong with your code. Here is a working example from the docs where I have added orderBy. https://plnkr.co/edit/37ReST5XyGdnzhzsVR9O?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much Alex